# Что такое __all__ в Python?

Tags: python

Объясните, пожалуйста, что такое `__all__` (я так понимаю, это некий список), в каких случаях он используется в Python и как это применяется при импортировании?

Читаю Бизли, но там как-то мудрёно написано и пример непонятный, я не понял, честно говоря. Гугление тоже особо не помогло...

Comment: Вот здесь очень хорошо про импорт написано: [http://asvetlov.blogspot.com/](http://asvetlov.blogspot.com/). Сам узнал там много нового ;)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`__all__` в Pythone - это список публичных объектов данного модуля. Т.е, допустим, у вас есть некий mymodule.py, в нем описано очень много объектов, и не требуется давать пользоваться ими всеми со стороны. В `__all__` в mymodule.py вы списком определяете названия объектов, которые можно импортировать (`__all__ = ["MyClass", "MyClass2"]`). 
Т.е., например при from mymodule import * импортированы будут только те объекты, которые вы описали в `__all__`.
 Возможно, директиву `__all__` правильно будет назвать одним из уровней инкапсуляции в Python.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Когда мы делаем  from mymodule import *, то доступными становятся  именно те, которые указаны в __all__
А вот если если мы с помощью import mymodule  например загружаем новое пространство имён, которое по сути как контейнер, то мы можем обращаться ко всем объектам mymodule и __all__ игнориться. Я это сейчас на примере проверил. Я прав?

Comment: Да, примерно так.